# why QMediaPlayer not work with QCoreApplication under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qmediaplayer, qcoreapplication

Qt version is 5.2, QMediaPlayer in below code doesn't work (doesn't play .mp3 audio file):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QGuiApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(&app);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("some_audio_file.mp3"));

    player->play();

    return app.exec();
}
```

the same code works under windows, but when use QGuiApplication instead, QMediaPlayer will play the audio file.

Below is the .pro file, please *NOTE* that, 'gui' is used for 'QGuiApplication'.

```
QT += gui multimedia

CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += console

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test3
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
SOURCES += test.cpp
```

Comment: Please paste your .pro file

Comment: I'd assume the OS X plugin for qtmultimedia has a QtGui dependency and thus cannot be loaded in a non-GUI application.